# Ubuntu panel keeps rearranging extensions randomly

Tags: gnome

I have a few gnome-shell extensions installed (weather, caps lock indicator, brightness slider ect..).

I have just realized that every time I restart my computer or go into lock screen the panel automatically rearranges icons to random places and it never stays the same.

Is it anyway possible to lock down the panel so it wont move any of the extensions and keep them in the same place?